# Получить посты предшествующих текущему по id get posts () WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Как в WordPress получить посты которые были опубликованы скорее чем пост с id *?

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby'     => 'id',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Так я получаю один последний пост, я еще хочу дописать условие чтобы получить один последний пост который опубликован скорее за пост с id например 1000? Не могу найти как нужно передать такое условие.
Думал так:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby'     => 'id',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array ( 
        array( 
                'key' => 'ID', 
                'value' => (int)($_POST['loadMorePost']), 
                'compare' => '<', 
        ), 
),
);
```

не сработало, наверное из-за того что meta_query применяется только для цель полей ...
Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить все посты, опубликованные ранее поста с id=479 (например), надо сначала определить дату этого поста, а потом сделать запрос на все посты с датой ранее вычисленной. Стандартными средствами аргументов запроса get_posts() это сделать нельзя. Надо создать фильтр `posts_where`, с помощью которого добавить в SQL-запрос к базе нужную фильтрацию по дате. Чтобы фильтр работал, надо отключить подавление фильтров `'suppress_filters' => false,`:

```
global $date;
$posts = get_posts( 'p=479' );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $date = $post->post_date;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$args = array(
    'numberposts'      => - 1,
    'category_name'    => 'uncategorized',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
);

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
    echo ' ' . $post->post_date;
    echo '<br>';
}

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

wp_reset_postdata();

function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    global $date;
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . $date . "'";

    return $where;
}
```

Для тестового примера установлена категория постов uncategorized. Результат можно посмотреть на [тестовом сайте](http://test.kagg.eu/so723724/) и сравнить со [стандартной страницей категории uncategorized](http://test.kagg.eu/category/uncategorized/). Пост 479 - это пост "Привет, мир!" от 14.08.2017.